# Prestashop 1.6 How to allow out of stock orders in Multistor

Tags: prestashop, stock

V1.6.0.9 Multistore, Advanced Stock Management

Hi,
I need to show the add to cart button on items even when they are out of stock so that they can still be ordered. This was fine before I changed the site to Multistore.

At the moment, when an item is out of stock there is no add to cart showing.

In the Admin -> Preferences -> Products I have the "Allow ordering of out-of-stock products" set to true for all stores and the store manly in concern.

In Admin -> Catalog -> Products  I have option Available for Order set as true and the product set to available everywhere.

I thought out of stock ordering needed be be set for each product as well in Products but I can't see where. Also, this did work for these products before the site was transformed to a multistore, however, it may be the issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must go to The product page (Catalog>Products)
Go to Quantities (from that specific product) and make sure that When out of stock is set to Default: Allow orders as set in the Products Preferences page.

Answer (score 0):

1) Setting the default behavior;

on the Admin -> Preferences -> products [PRODUCTS STOCK] section you can set the default behavior for shops as to how to handle out of stock products:

Yes (cart will be shown for Out of stock)

No (no cart for out of stock)

2) Setting products out of stock behavior for each shop;

much easier doing on the DB table there is a table called (ps_)stock_available; where for each product in each shop the out of stock behavior can be defined on column (out_of_stock) with below values;

0 : no cart on out of stock

1 : out of stock order-able (cart will be shown)

2 : following the shop default behavior (as set in first step above)

setting to 2 might be preferred since updating shop behavior will be much easier whereas setting to 1 will require another DB update on each product in case of modifying your shops' out of stock behavior.

columns (id_shop) and (id_product) address each product in each of the shops, and column (id_product_attribute) accordingly will allow setting similar behavior on products with various models / attributes

Comment: can you check and improve answer with https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks